# how to solve the dependency missing in eclipse by mvn?

Tags: eclipse, maven, servlets, jetty

I get a java servlet project from github, it use mvn to compile ,and use jetty as the servlet container.Since I never used mvn ,so I get much problems/.

question 1:
When I run mvn install , it says "BUILD SUCCESS",but after I import this project into eclipse, many packages imported cannot be resolved by eclipse. Why ?It seems that when I run "mvn install",mvn has downloaded all dependencies for me.

question 2:
How to deploy my project to jetty and then run all jUnit test cases ?

question 3:
when I run "mvn jetty:run",it  says:

```
No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/root/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

Google says I should add jetty plugins to mvn configuration .But I am confused about the project.Why doesn't  the project developers add this to pom.xml?Or, there exist other solutions?

below is the simple project directory.Project name is http-request.

```
[root@localhost http-request]# ls
lib  pom.xml  README.md
[root@localhost http-request]# cd lib
[root@localhost lib]# ls
pom.xml  src  target
```

pom.xml under http-request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.github.kevinsawicki</groupId>
  <artifactId>http-request-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>lib</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

pom.xml under http-request/lib:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
    <version>7</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.github.kevinsawicki</groupId>
  <artifactId>http-request</artifactId>
  <version>5.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <url>https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request</url>
  <description>Library for making HTTP requests</description>
  <inceptionYear>2011</inceptionYear>

  <issueManagement>
    <url>https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request/issues</url>
    <system>GitHub Issues</system>
  </issueManagement>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jetty.version>8.1.9.v20130131</jetty.version>
  </properties>

  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>MIT License</name>
      <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <scm>
    <url>https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request</url>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:kevinsawicki/http-request.git</developerConnection>
  </scm>

  <developers>
    <developer>
      <email>kevinsawicki@gmail.com</email>
      <name>Kevin Sawicki</name>
      <url>https://github.com/kevinsawicki</url>
      <id>kevinsawicki</id>
    </developer>
  </developers>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Require-Bundle />
            <Export-Package>!.,com.github.kevinsawicki.http</Export-Package>
            <Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment>J2SE-1.5</Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>bundle-manifest</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>manifest</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
        <artifactId>site-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
        <configuration>
          <message>Generated site for ${project.name} ${project.version}</message>
          <noJekyll>true</noJekyll>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>site</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <reportPlugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.2</version>
              <configuration>
                <dependencyDetailsEnabled>true</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                <dependencyLocationsEnabled>true</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.8</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-changelog-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
            </plugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>sign</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>sign</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Used to test proxy -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
      <version>${jetty.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues raised. Let me divide my answer.

### Running builds as root

I highly recommend that you stop running builds as root.

```
[root@localhost http-request]# ls
lib  pom.xml  README.md
[root@localhost http-request]# cd lib
[root@localhost lib]# ls
pom.xml  src  target
```

This is a dangerous practice. Create a normal user account on your system and use this.

### Dependencies missing in Eclipse

I have tested the project you are building and confirmed that it builds as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request.git
cd http-request
mvn install
```

You state that it fails when run from within Eclipse? Could this be because you have not installed the Eclipse plugin for Maven? See the following question:

- [How can I make eclipse make use of packages downloaded by maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284714/how-can-i-make-eclipse-make-use-of-packages-downloaded-by-maven)

### No plugin found for prefix 'jetty'

This error is being thrown because the build has not been configured to use jetty. You need to read the documentation on how to enable this in your build

- http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/maven-and-jetty.html

Your question here:

> Google says I should add jetty plugins to mvn configuration .But I am confused about the project.Why doesn't the project developers add this to pom.xml?Or, there exist other solutions?

Needs to be addresses to the developer of the project. The most likely explanation is that he is not using Jetty to test his code. For example in my projects I use a continuous integration server ([Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)) which automatically builds, deploys and tests code every time a code commit is made.