# How can I make eclipse make use of packages downloaded by maven?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

When I use Maven compile, it will automatically download the depended java packages for me.  Now, to debug the project, I import the project into Eclipse, but in Eclipse, the depended package is still missing.  How can I get the packages?  Or, can Eclipse use packages downloaded by Maven?

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to manually add all the dependencies downloaded by maven to the classpath in Eclipse. There is a [maven-2-eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin which integrates maven with Eclipse. Using that plugin you can

- import/create  a project as Maven project or
- convert an existing project into a maven project

Your Eclipse will automatically add all the downloaded dependencies on the class path everytime.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer,it partially solved my problem.But another problem appeared.Please refer to my another question link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310224/i-used-m2eclipse-plugins-in-eclipse-why-the-imported-package-still-cannot-be-res

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the m2e eclipse maven plugin suggested by rocketboy is to use the [maven eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/). This works from the command line (`mvn eclipse:eclipse`), and generates Eclipse settings for your project by downloading dependencies and putting them onto the Eclipse build path.